# g++ compilation undefined references on external hpp file

Tags: c++, xml, linux, gcc

I am trying to include [pugixml.hpp](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml/blob/master/src/pugixml.hpp) in my code using the following include notation :

```
#include "pugixml-1.7/src/pugixml.hpp"
```

Now the weird thing is, this runs in Codeblocks fine, but when I am trying to run it via terminal (I have all the source codes in one single file) using g++ :

```
g++-5 -v -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -pedantic -fopenmp -pthread main.cpp -o main.o
```

It throws out a bunch of `undefined reference to pugi::xml..` (whichever the api I was using). I have tried everything, by keeping the pugixml.hpp file in the main directory, by adding bunch of flags like `-iquote` or `-c` to point to that directory.. but nothing is working. What else I should try? I am including the output till directory search here :

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-5
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~12.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.1 20151031 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~12.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-std=c++11' '-O3' '-Wall' '-Wpedantic' '-fopenmp' '-pthread' '-o' 'main.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-pthread'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase main -O3 -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -version -fopenmp -fstack-protector -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccXfMWIT.s
GNU C++11 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~12.04) version 5.2.1 20151031 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.2.1 20151031, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

Comment: Link required libraries.

Comment: i have linked all required libraries using the "#include". pugixml takes only two files, pugixml.hpp and pugixmlconfig.hpp

Comment: You may need to provide the include path on the command line. (ie. `g++ -I/path/to/includes ...`).

Comment: @callyalater do you mean by using -c flag? tried it too, didn't work :(

Comment: @KoustuvSinha Are you sure? I also see [`pubixml.cpp`](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml/blob/master/src/pugixml.cpp) in the repository. (Note: Do not use `#include` for "linking" cpp files)

Comment: @KoustuvSinha No, I do not mean by using the `-c` flag. I mean the `-I` flag.

Comment: tried it, still same error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link against the compiled `pugixml` library. Including the `pugixml.hpp` is simply telling the preprocessor to get the interface, however the compiler (more specifically the linker) needs to find the appropriate compiled `pugixml` code for it to be usable from your source code.

Comment: do u mean i need to link pugixml.o in the code compilation? which flag does that?

Comment: @KoustuvSinha [This website](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/02wi/unix/g++.html) might help out.

Comment: @Koustav Sinha: Yes. I haven't used gcc from the command line directly in a long time, but I believe you do that with the -o. In cmake it would be target_link_libraries().

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to link the library. Based on your compiler output, you seem to be running Ubuntu. The easiest way to install the library on Ubuntu is by installing the `libpugixml-dev` package. This will install `pugixml.hpp` under `/usr/include`, and `libpugixml.so` under `/usr/lib`.

```bash
sudo apt install libpugixml-dev
```

One of the standard ways to use installed libraries is by including the output of `pkg-config` on the compiler command line:

```bash
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fopenmp -pthread $(pkg-config --libs --cflags pugixml) -o main main.cpp
```

Alternatively, you can add the `-lpugixml` flag yourself to link against `libpugixml.so`, and rely on the headers being automatically found under `/usr/include`.

```bash
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fopenmp -pthread -lpugixml -o main main.cpp
```

For all of the above to work, you will need to change your include line to not include the installation path, only `pugixml.hpp`:

```cpp
#include "pugixml.hpp"
```